# Regular expression or javascript to isolate a div with a specific class and it's closing </div>

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to find a regex that will match HTML that is in a string starting with `<div class="table-responsive"` with it's closing `</div>` tag, ignoring the closing divs that don't close the div with the class `"table-responsive"`. I downloaded HTML from another page on a website with Javascript and I'm setting the innerHTML of a div to contain the info I want displayed from the downloaded HTML. The problem is that I only want the tag starting with `<div class="table-responsive"` and the closing div displayed and I'm trying to cut out everything but I don't know what the best method is to do that. Can anyone make a suggestion how I can do that?

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Comment: Regular expressions are very bad at matching balanced patterns like HTML. Use an HTML parser, not regexp.

Comment: How is this downloaded HTML page stored? Are you wanting to load it with AJAX and then grab the information you need from it?

Comment: @Andy I'm pulling it from an iframe using this code http://jsfiddle.net/XYjuX/1/

Comment: @paulpearce: Does the answer address your needs? I so, care to accept the answer? If not edit your question to clarify what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use regex, first by adding nesting level info to `div`s, extracting the relevant range based on nesting level, and removing the nesting level info.

It is much easier to convert the HTML to an in-memory DOM, and extract the relevant data. Here is an approach using jQuery:

```js
const html = '<div class="top"> <div class="table-responsive"> <div class="inner1"> <div class="inner2">blah</div> </div> </div> </div>';
let extractedHtml = $(html).find('.table-responsive').prop('outerHTML');
console.log(extractedHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Output:

```
<div class="table-responsive"> <div class="inner1"> <div class="inner2">blah</div> </div> </div>
```

If you only want the HTML inside the `div` tag use this:

```
let extractedHtml = $(html).find('.table-responsive').html();
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a parser you can properly parse nested structures with regex using three steps: 1. add nesting level to opening and closing tags, 2. identify matching opening and closing tag based on annotated nesting level, 3. clean up nesting level annotation. More at twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201109x3